# PHP Remove All Non-alphanumeric Characters Except Apostrophes

Tags: preg-replace, str-replace, trim, alphanumeric, apostrophe

```
$keywords = explode("\n",$_POST['keywords']);

//Inserting into Database
foreach($keywords as $key => $keyword){
    $keyword = strtolower(trim($keyword));
    $keyword = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9' ]/", "", $keyword);
    $keyword = preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $keyword);
    $insertkeywords = "INSERT IGNORE INTO kwdb (keyword) VALUES ('$keyword')";
        mysql_query($insertkeywords);
}
```

I can't for the life of me figure out why this code won't insert the keywords into the database when I have an apostrophe in the:

```
"/[^A-Za-z0-9' ]/"
```

But when I remove it to be:

```
"/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/"
```

This script inserts records into the database.

**What am I trying to do?**
I have a textarea on a form.  For each keyword on a new line, I explode based on the \n.  I want to remove all non-letter and non-number characters from the keywords but don't want apostrophes to be removed.

I basically want all keywords to be lower-case with leading, trailing and extra white spaces - 2 or more blank spaces trimmed down to one - removed along with any non-letter and non-number characters except for apostrophes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your keyword: $insertkeywords = "INSERT IGNORE INTO kwdb (keyword) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($keyword)."')";

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [clover](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1982115/clover). Without your help, it would have taken me many hours to figure that one out!  I ended up using [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) instead of [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) because mysql_real_escape_string says it is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0.  As a result, I had to change it up a bit but the below code seems to work great for me so far (in case anyone else runs across this).

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
  }
else
    {
echo "Connected Successfully!";
}
//select database
mysqli_select_db($con, "test");

$keywords = explode("\n",$_POST['keywords']);

//Inserting into Database
foreach($keywords as $key => $keyword){
    $keyword = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9' ]/", " ", $keyword);
    $keyword = preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $keyword);
    $keyword = strtolower(trim($keyword));
    //$insertkeywords = "INSERT IGNORE INTO kwdb (keyword) VALUES ('$keyword')";
    $insertkeywords = "INSERT IGNORE INTO kwdb (keyword) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $keyword)."')";
        mysqli_query($con, $insertkeywords);
}
```